# Javascript: insert array in another array at a specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

I'd like to insert b at index 1 of a, to have :

```
c = [1,4,5,6,2,3]
```

Is there a builtin function to do this ?
I found the answer for a single element, but not for a whole array. 
I imagine something like `concat` but with an additional parameter which would be the index of insertion.

Comment: You can use `splice` with spread syntax `a.splice(1, 0, ...b)`

Answer (score 4):

```js
var a = [1,2,3],
    b = [4,5,6];
    a.splice(1, 0, ...b);
    
    console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

```js
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

// copy array a
c = a.slice();
// provide array of arguments using apply method
// and insert elements using splice method
[].splice.apply(c, [1, 0].concat(b))

console.log(c);
```